# Bug: \u200b and \u200c characters added to code snippet in comment

Tags: bug, code, special-characters

See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment985615_3122) in the Stack Exchange sandbox. I quote it here:

> Have a look at this JS code: `document.body.removeChild(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')));` If you manually type it into your browser console it will work, but copying and pasting from my comment will throw an error because Stack Exchange randomly adds `\u200b` and `\u200c` characters for no apparent reason. You can even manually type it in a comment on Stack Exchange, then copy and paste again, and it still won't work.

Comment: Is the code providing an answer? If so, post it as an answer. Is it providing a clarification to the question? If so, edit the question.

Comment: @Andy the code is merely an example of the bug in how Stack Exchange renders some inline code in comments.

Comment: My point is, why are you posting code in a comment that is so long? Comments are not for code blocks. That's not their purpose.